# problemas con una consulta pivot eloquent en laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model-view-controller

mi consulta surge porque tengo una webapp que es un ecommerce, tengo la tabla carrito que tiene user_id, product_id, quantity y puntosretiros_id. Quiero hacer una consulta de todo para el admin después pueda gestionar los pedidos. 
El tema es que estoy segura que no lo estoy planteando bien. Por lo que vi en los diferentes modelos hay que poner belongTo, hasMany y etc. Pero yo tengo una function carrito en donde solo en users tengo el query (lo hice en un curso hace tiempo y ya no me acuerdo bien como se planteaba, asique medio que lo copie cambiando las variables) trate de dos formas, pero no se me ocurre como hacerlo funcionar. Pongo capturas de lo que cambie en el model y el error que me tira el navegador (no pongo el view porque es solo un dd de la una variable donde guardo la consulta)

el model de user, intento 1

```
    public function cart(){

       return $this->belongsToMany(Cart::class, 'users')-     
       >withPivot('user_id','product_id', 'quantity','puntosretiros_id');
    }
```

el controller

```
public function index()
    {


      $datoUsuario =Auth::user();

      $productos=$datoUsuario->carrito;

      $punto = $datoUsuario->cart->user_id;

      return view('/resumen/index')->with(['datoUsuario' => $datoUsuario,'cart' => 
      $cart,'productos'=> $productos]);
    }
```

el error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora subo lo que intente. Solo cambie en el model, en la function cart 'users', por Auth::user(), que en el fondo sabia que iba a fallar, pero me sirvió para darme cuenta de que los datos los trae, pero mal XD

el model donde cambie la function cart

```
public function cart()
    {

      return $this->belongsToMany(Cart::class, Auth::user())- 
      >withPivot('user_id','product_id', 'quantity','puntosretiros_id');
    }
```

el error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno, eso es todo. Si a alguien se le ocurre (o sabe :p) como puedo puedo arreglarlo, se agradece un montón alguna idea. Saludos ^^

Comment: Las instrucciones `belongsToMany` reciben como parametro el nombre del modelo y el siguiente es el nombre de la tabla

Comment: `return $this->belongsToMany(Cart::class, 'table_has_tabla')........`